# Контекстное меню HTML

Tags: html, html5, меню

Элемент не добавляется

```css
.cmenu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #29668f;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="cmenu" contextmenu="mycontextmenu">
  <p align="center">right click pls</p>
</div>
<menu type="context" id="mycontextmenu">
  <menuitem label="Не надо тыкать сюда"></menuitem>
</menu>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: В чем вопрос? Что именно должно быть?

Comment: И содержимое скрипта добавьте в сниппет, чтобы мы его увидели.

Answer (score 1):

`menuitem` для контекстного меню работает [только в firefox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_menuitem.asp)

собственно в firefox пункт меню отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]